# Dreamy musical phenomenon

Tags: harmony, melody

It happens mainly when I am relaxed, about to sleep or near to wake up, but it also happens other times but less often, generally on quiet environments, then I start to listen a music on my head, most of the times it is a song I know, but it also happens to listen a unknown melody, maybe it is a composition of several songs I have listened before mixed together within something pleasurable but new for me.

The song is played so sharp it seems to be going from my ears, the bass are so loud it shivers my body, and it seems I have no control about what is being played, sometimes it is played different songs one after another.

When it have vocals I listen the original singer voice, even on songs I have never memorized the lyrics, and I also happen to listen some Japanese songs out of this state, and sometimes this phenomenon happens to play Japanese music that I would never be able to sing, but not only the melody but also the lyrics seems to be correct on the original idiom.

I want to know if there are more people had already gone through this phenomenon and if it has name?

Comment: It sounds like you have a good memory for music. I often listen to music in my head; it is a reason for disliking piped music in supermarkets.

Comment: I think I have something similar, but the most I could come up with it was EHS, since most of the time it's not really music, it's more like a loud static and pressure, but sometimes it evolves into music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is actually a real thing (nothing to worry about) that a lot of people experience. Its called a Musical hallucination (oOh.) Its basically where you randomly remember bits and parts of a song or tune, and your brain starts playing them like they're actually there. They are a specific kind of Auditory Hallucinations, where people hear the noise as if it were happening right there in front of them. People have been known to even "hear" people talking to them from previous conversations, and they respond, just talking to themselves. Musical hallucinations aren't really anything to be worried about, but if it starts getting worse, that could be a sign of tinnitus or paracusia. All of these conditions are still being studied because they are so complex and interesting.